# "Server Error in '/' Application"

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql, sql-server

When i click a button, to store data in a remote sql database, it keeps giving me this error, even after i deleted the `datetime` type table in the db.

The table is also nullable now, but what puzzles me, is the fact that i'm not really storing anything into this `datetime` table, i really don't know what to think.

Here's the stack trace of the error:

```
Error de servidor en la aplicación '/'.

Desbordamiento de SqlDateTime. Debe estar entre 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM y 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Descripción: Excepción no controlada al ejecutar la solicitud Web actual. Revise el seguimiento de la pila para obtener más información acerca del error y dónde se originó en el código. 

Detalles de la excepción: System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException: Desbordamiento de SqlDateTime. Debe estar entre 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM y 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Error de código fuente: 


Línea 23:             db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
Línea 24:             //Sumbit changes to the database
Línea 25:             db.SubmitChanges();
Línea 26:         }
Línea 27: 

Archivo de origen: c:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\Botones.cs    Línea: 25 

Seguimiento de la pila: 


[SqlTypeException: Desbordamiento de SqlDateTime. Debe estar entre 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM y 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.]
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC(_SqlRPC[] rpcArray, Int32 timeout, Boolean inSchema, SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean isCommandProc, Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 startRpc, Int32 startParam) +5635
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +1325
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite) +175
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method) +53
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method) +134
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader(CommandBehavior behavior) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader() +12
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute(Expression query, QueryInfo queryInfo, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] parentArgs, Object[] userArgs, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries, Object lastResult) +1306
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll(Expression query, QueryInfo[] queryInfos, IObjectReaderFactory factory, Object[] userArguments, ICompiledSubQuery[] subQueries) +118
  System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute(Expression query) +342
System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert(TrackedObject item) +145
System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.Insert(TrackedObject item) +215
System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +378
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges(ConflictMode failureMode) +372
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges() +23
Grupo_Zulcon.Botones.SaveCVInfo2(String varOne, String varTwo, String varThree) in c:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\Botones.cs:25
Grupo_Zulcon.EnvianosTuCurriculum.Button1_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e) in c:\Users\Kristian\Documents\zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\Grupo Zulcon\EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs:32
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +9553594
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +103
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String eventArgument) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1724
```

And this what i reference in button:

```
 public void SaveCVInfo2(string varOne,string varTwo, string  varThree)
{
    using (ConexionGeneralDataContext db = new ConexionGeneralDataContext())
    {
        Usuario_Web columna = new Usuario_Web();
        //Add new values to each fields
        columna.Nombre = varOne;
        columna.Apellido = varTwo;
        columna.Em_solicitado = varThree;
        //and the rest where the textboxes would have been


        //Insert the new Customer object
        db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit(columna);
        //Sumbit changes to the database
        db.SubmitChanges();
    }

}
```

Can anyone shed some light upon this?

EDIT stacktrace in **english**:

```
Server Error in '/' Application .

SqlDateTime overflow . Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM.

Description : An unhandled exception when running the current Web request . Check the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details : System.Data.SqlTypes.SqlTypeException : SqlDateTime overflow . Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM .

Source Error :


Line 23 : db.Usuario_Web.InsertOnSubmit (column) ;
Line 24 : / / Sumbit changes to the database
Line 25 : db.SubmitChanges ();
Line 26 : }
Line 27 :

Source File: c: \ Users \ Kristian \ Documents \ zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ Botones.cs Line : 25

Stack Trace :


[ SqlTypeException : SqlDateTime overflow . Must be between 1/1/1753 12:00:00 AM and 12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM . ]
System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TdsExecuteRPC ( _SqlRPC [ ] rpcArray , Int32 timeout , Boolean inSchema , SqlNotificationRequest notificationRequest , TdsParserStateObject stateObj , Boolean isCommandProc , Boolean sync, TaskCompletionSource ` 1 completion , startRpc Int32 , Int32 startParam ) +5635
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds ( CommandBehavior cmdBehavior , RunBehavior runBehavior , Boolean returnStream , Boolean async , Int32 timeout , Task & task , Boolean asyncWrite ) +1325
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader ( CommandBehavior cmdBehavior , RunBehavior runBehavior , Boolean returnStream , String method , TaskCompletionSource ` 1 completion , Int32 timeout , Task & task , Boolean asyncWrite ) +175
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader ( CommandBehavior cmdBehavior , RunBehavior runBehavior , Boolean returnStream , String method) +53
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader ( CommandBehavior behavior, String method ) +134
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteDbDataReader ( CommandBehavior behavior ) +41
System.Data.Common.DbCommand.ExecuteReader ( ) +12
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.Execute (Expression query , QueryInfo QueryInfo , IObjectReaderFactory factory , Object [ ] parentArgs , Object [ ] userArgs , ICompiledSubQuery [ ] Subqueries , Object LastResult ) died 1306
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.ExecuteAll (Expression query , QueryInfo [ ] queryInfos , IObjectReaderFactory factory , Object [ ] userArguments , ICompiledSubQuery [ ] SubQueries ) +118
```

```
System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlProvider.System.Data.Linq.Provider.IProvider.Execute (Expression query) +342
System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.DynamicInsert ( TrackedObject item) +145
System.Data.Linq.StandardChangeDirector.Insert ( TrackedObject item) +215
System.Data.Linq.ChangeProcessor.SubmitChanges ( ConflictMode failureMode ) +378
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges ( ConflictMode failureMode ) +372
System.Data.Linq.DataContext.SubmitChanges ( ) +23
Grupo_Zulcon.Botones.SaveCVInfo2 (String Varone , varTwo String , String varThree ) in c: \ Users \ Kristian \ Documents \ zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ Botones.cs : 25
Grupo_Zulcon.EnvianosTuCurriculum.Button1_Click ( Object sender , EventArgs e) in c: \ Users \ Kristian \ Documents \ zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ Group Zulcon \ EnvianosTuCurriculum.aspx.cs : 32
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick ( EventArgs e) +9553594
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent (String eventArgument ) +103
System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent (String eventArgument ) +10
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent ( IPostBackEventHandler SourceControl , String eventArgument ) +13
System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent ( NameValueCollection postData ) +35
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain (Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint , Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint ) +1724
```

Comment: Have you removed the DateTime column in the database and updated th EF context after that?

Comment: What he said, but with emphasis on "updated the EF context". And next time, ***[traducirlo por favor](http://translate.google.com/#en/es/translate%20it%2C%20please)***.

Comment: Updated, deleted datetime field, and it works now, but i'm still thinking about the error, i mean i'll need that datetime table, i don't know if it's about a permission issue from Visual Studio to the remote Database, maybe i should add it from there, and not directly on sql-server...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like it's a problem with your dates. One of the columns you're updating appears to be a date, but you're passing it as a string. SQL will do it's best to parse this date, but that might result in an out-of-range date, hence the error.

Using `DateTime.Parse` in your code before you set the value.

It may also help to post the error message in English if possible.

Comment: Sorry :), made an edit to my question, stack trace it's translated now